# LocalDate wrong output with WeekFields

Tags: java, localdate, week-number

I need to get the first and the last day of a date composed by a year and a week. I tried this code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
      int year = 2021;
      int week = 29;
      // first day of the week
      System.out.println(LocalDate.now()
                        .withYear(year)
                        .with(weekFields.weekOfYear(), week)
                        .with(weekFields.dayOfWeek(), 1));
      // last day of the week
      System.out.println(LocalDate.now()
                        .withYear(year)
                        .with(weekFields.weekOfYear(), week)
                        .with(weekFields.dayOfWeek(), 7));
    }
}
```

My default Locale is `it_IT` and the output was correct, first day was `19/07/2021` and last day was `25/07/2021` ([year week IT](https://www.epochconverter.com/it/settimane/2021), format is dd/mm/yyyy).

I stopped the application and before running it I set the VM arguments `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=UK` to test a different Locale but once run again the output was completely wrong.

For the week `29` of the year `2021` I expected the first day of the week to be `2021-07-19` and the last day `2021-07-25` ([year week UK](http://calendaruk.co.uk/week-numbers-2021/)) but I instead got `2021-07-11` as the first day of the week and `2021-07-17` as the last day of the week.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: *-Duser.region=UK* should be `-Duser.country=GB` I think. I get the expected outputs, run for Locales it_IT and en_GB

Comment: You're right. Just tested and works. Such a bad mistake, thank you for helping. If you want you can answer so I can mark as resolved.

Comment: Can't unfortunately. It's been closed

Comment: The links provided by the the private feedback didn't help as much as your comment. That's unfortunate..

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of early question-closing here, but I understand that erring on the side of caution is better than having gazillions of questions that are essentially duplicates